# PHP outputs \ chars randomly

Tags: php

I have a PHP script for saving an image.

Here comes my code:

```
move_uploaded_file($filename, $imagePath . $_FILES["img"]["name"]);

$tempPath = $imagePath . $_FILES['img']['name'];

$response = array(
        "status" => 'success', 
        "url" => $tempPath, 
        "width" => $width, 
        "height" => $height
    );

echo json_encode($response);
```

The weird thing: When I `echo $tempPath` BEFORE the array, in the "Network" tab in my Chrome Developer Tools I get the right output: "uploads/temp/imagename.png".

However, in my array the key "url" has the value: "uploads/\temp/imagename.png"

So my question is: Why does `$tempPath` have a different value in my response array? Where do the `"\"` chars come from?

Comment: This code doesn't output anything, so it won't give either of the results you describe. You need to include enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since this code doesn't actually output anything, the problem will be in the particulars of how exactly you output; which you will need to show us.

Comment: show us the code you use to view your array contents

Comment: I use "echo json_encode($response)"

Comment: That's just JSON encoding, it's escaping the slashes in your string.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a different value.

`\/` is a perfectly acceptable way to represent a `/` character in the JSON data format and PHP uses that way by default.

Comment: How do I prevent this? My path needs to be put out correctly of course

Comment: It is being put out correctly. You will get the value you expect when you run it through a JSON parser.